# Edit only works on first page, might some wrong with modal?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, laravel

I have a page showing products details. When I click on any product we can edit it but the problem is when I go to the next page of the products, it doesn't work or show the last clicked product of the first page (Javascript not working on other than first page).

That is the main Product.blade part----

```
        <div class="modal fade" id="changeAlertQuantity" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                Change Alert Quantity & Unit Price
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('changeAlertQuanityAndUnitPrice') }}">
                  {{ csrf_field() }}
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name" class="col-md-4 control-label">Product ID</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" name="product_name" readonly="">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="alert_quantity" class="col-md-4 control-label">Alert Quantity</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <input id="alert_quantity" type="text" class="form-control" name="alert_quantity" required="">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                 <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4">
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                        Submit
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

-------Javascript--------

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#product-list-table').DataTable({
        "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
        "lengthMenu": [ [10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"] ]
      });


      $(".tableData").click(function(){
        var name = $(this).children('td:first').html();
        var alert_quantity = $(this).closest('tr').children('td.alertQ').html();

        $("#name").val(name);
        $("#alert_quantity").val(alert_quantity);
      });
```

The first page and we can edit properly:

[image: success]

In the second page, on clicking, it shows the first page product and doesn't edit anything that's not on the 1st page

[image: failure]

I also tried to expand the first page products list but then it still only shows the first ten products' edit option.

Comment: you may post the current HTML and scripts in codepen and to get a better idea of what is going on